# Changing multiple elements in a numpy array and their neighbours, with no loops

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking for execution speed (application in image processing) so no loops. The idea is to have some single points, in this example (5, 5), (9, 7), (15, 16), and turn them and neighbouring elements (dictated by offset value) to one.

```
zero = np.zeros((20, 20))
offset = 1
idx0 = np.array([5, 9, 15]).T-offset
idx0b = np.array([5, 9, 15]).T+offset
idx1 = np.array([5, 7, 16]).T-offset
idx1b = np.array([5, 7, 16]).T+offset

zero[idx0:idx0b,idx1:idx1b] = 1
```

I'm getting this error.

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you want [image dilation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.binary_dilation).

Comment: That's actually even better than a square mask, Thank you!!!!